# Zend/PHP: How to remove all leading 0s from string?

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

I have a string which contains only numbers. Now I want to remove all leading 0s from that string

For example:

```
input: 000000001230
output: 1230


input: 01000
output: 1000
```

Is there any function in PHP/Zend for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$myvar = ltrim('01000','0');
```

Answer (score 6):

No. There is only [`Zend_Filter_StringTrim`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Filter/StringTrim.php), but that does not `ltrim`, but `preg_replace` (unicode aware though) from both ends. Either

- write a custom filter that just trims from the left or
- use the [solution offered by oezi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636620/zend-php-how-to-remove-all-leading-0s-from-string/2636633#2636633) or

use [`Zend_Filter_Callback`](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Filter/Callback.php):

```
echo Zend_Filter::filterStatic('000111000', 'Callback', array('ltrim', '0'));
// gives 111000
```

or with a filter instance

```
$trimmer = new Zend_Filter_Callback('ltrim', '0');
echo $trimmer->filter('000111000'); // gives 111000
```

This way you could use it in a Filter chain.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just cast to int?

```
$s = '00000414';
print (int)$s; // 414
```

Answer (score 3):

Zend_Filter_Int will also work for this particular case.